# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted, CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django-forms

I know this problem has been posted a lot, but I've been trying all the suggested solutions until now and none has worked.

**login.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Connexion{% endblock %}

{% block bodyId %}loginPage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="login" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<p>
<input type ="submit" name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value="Se connecter" />
<a href="/register"> Créer un compte</a>
</p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is my **view.py** part:

```
def login(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        logged_user = Personne.objects.get(courriel=user_email)
        request.session['logged_user_id'] = logged_user.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome')
else: 
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your submit button to something other than csrfmiddlewaretoken. It's clashing with the hidden field that actually contains your token and is causing the error.